# jquery keyup holding shift and number pad keys

Tags: jquery, shift, keyup

I am not getting the right codes for some number pad keys when holding the shift key down. This is happening only for the numbers keys and point/del key on the number pad when the num-lock key is on.

```
$('body').keyup(function (e) {

            alert('key code ' + e.keyCode + '  ewhich: ' + e.which);
});
```

With num-lock ON:

Shift + numberPad1 outputs code 16, and so for all number keys on keypad and the point/del key.

Any explanation for this?

USING CHROME

Comment: 16 is the `Shift` code; [here's a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: I am testing on Chrome

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows PC, Shift+Numpad(0-9) have different functionality due to the shift key temporarily overriding the 'Numlock=ON' state. e.g. Shift+Numpad1 will register as "End" and release the Shift key. This has been the source of a 2.5 year headache for me in trying to use the same shortcuts I have assigned for an app I use on my Mac when using the same app on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

KeyUp event will fire when you up last key that means when you press shift+numpad1, shift ket is up at the last that is why you are getting 16 code.

Use Keydown event that will give you accurate result.
You want to trace shift +key code then you have to handel shift key seprately

Exp-

> $(document).ready(function() {
>
> ```
>     $("body").keydown(function (e) {
>
>         console.log('key code ' + e.keyCode + '  ewhich: ' + e.which);
>
>     });
>
> });
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Shift key is kept pressed, not up, the one that goes up is the numpad key. It is very weird because doing the same (keeping shift pressed) and trying any key other than the numpads will return that other key's code and not the shift code (16).

Comment: I cannot ignore those codes 16 because when keyup get a code 16 I call an action. This is what I am doing: While shift is pressed, I read the number keys entered to make a number by concatenating all the numbers entered, then when the shift is released I invoke an action using that number as an argument for a function. I am implementing a shortcut functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing here. And in this case, maybe was passing two times on the keyup, one for the key that you want, and other to shift.
Try to ignore the code 16, and it will work fine.

```
$('body').keyup(function (e) {
  if(!e.keyCode == 16)
    console.log('key code ' + e.keyCode + ' shiftKey' + e.shiftKey);
});
```

Or try to use keypress

```
$('body').keypress(function (e) {
  console.log('key code ' + e.keyCode + ' shiftKey' + e.shiftKey);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fact is that I cannot ignore the KeyUp for shift, since I need it to commit an action. This is what I am doing: While shift is pressed, I read the number keys entered to make a number by concatenating all the numbers entered, then when the shift is released I invoke an action using that number as an argument for a function. I am implementing a shortcut functionality.

Comment: So I don't understand what your problem. Here using keyup always will fire the event  two times, one for the key and other to shift. Note that the numbers of the numpad have different codes of normal keyboard.